# jQuery submit button doesn't work on load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

when i load the page normally everything is going, the form is submitted and i get the right responses .. but when i load the page with `.load()` function jQuery the form doesnt submitted! and i get nothing from Ajax function!! any help

this is my HTML :

```
                   <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4>Manage Contents</h4>
                            <div class="table-responsive table3">
                              <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Content</th>
                                    <th>Owner</th>
                                    <th>Created Date</th>
                                    <th>Project</th>
                                    <th>Priorty</th>
                                    <th>Options</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @if ($availabe >= 1 )
                                  <?php $i =1; ?>
                                  @foreach ($avashown as $key)

                              <?php //this is edit content form?>
                              @if(isset($index) && $index == $i && isset($editid) && isset($idexist) && $idexist == $key->id)
                                <tr>
                                <form id="edit-content-form" action="/testajax" method="POST">
                                    <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                                    <td hidden="hidden">{{ csrf_field() }}</td>
                                    <td hidden="hidden"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $editid }}"></td>
                                    <td hidden="hidden"><input type="hidden" name="index" value="{{ $index }}"></td>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                      <div class="control-group" id="inputField1">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="content" value="{{ $key->content }}">
                                        <span class="help-block hideme" id="help-block1"></span>
                                      </div>
                                    </td>                                    
                                      <td colspan="1">
                                        <div class="control-group" id="inputField2">
                                          <select class="form-control" name="project">
                                            @foreach ($projects as $project)
                                              <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->projectname }}</option>
                                              @endforeach
                                          </select>
                                          <span class="help-block hideme" id="help-block2"></span>
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <td colspan="1">
                                        <div class="control-group" id="inputField3">
                                          <select class="form-control" name="priority">
                                              @foreach ($priorities as $priority)
                                              <option value="{{ $priority->id }}">{{ $priority->value }}</option>
                                              @endforeach
                                          </select>
                                          <span class="help-block hideme" id="help-block3"></span>
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <input type="submit" id="submitForm" name="submit" value="Done">
                                      </td>
                                    </form>
                                </tr>
                              <?php $i++;//i have to increase it here again?>
                              @else
                              <tr>
                              <td class="hidden"></td>
                                <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $key->content }}</td>
                                <?php $firstname = \App\User::find($key->owner_id);?>
                                <td>{{ ucfirst($firstname->firstname) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $key->created_at }}</td>
                                <?php $projectname = \App\Project::find($key->project_id);?>
                                <td>{{ $projectname-> projectname }}</td>
                                <?php $priorty = \App\Priority::find($key->priority_id);?>
                                <td><span class ="label label-{{ $priorty->name }}">{{ $priorty->value }}<span></td>

                                <td>
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete" onclick="ContentStatus('delete/ajax/{{ $key->id }}')"></span><span>&nbsp;</span>

                                  <span id="editContentGlyph" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" onclick="editContent({{ $i }},{{ $key->id }})"></span>

                                </td>
                              <?php $i++; ?>
                              </tr>
                              @endif
                                @endforeach
                              @else
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>0</td>
                                      <td colspan="6">Let's Work and Add some Contents! <a href="/new_content" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Create">Create</a></td>
                                  </tr>
                            @endif
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`
```

this is my script file :

```
function editContent(index,id){

    var place  = ".table3 tbody tr:nth-child("+index+") " ;
    var place  = "#alltables" ;
    var des    = place+" > *";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( place ).load("http://localhost:8000/manage_contents/"+index+"/"+id+" "+des, function(){
    });
});
}


$(document).ready(function(){

$(function(){
    $('#edit-content-form').on('submit',function(e){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        })
        e.preventDefault(e);

            $.ajax({

            type:"PUT",
            url:'http://localhost:8000/testajax',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data){
                $("#alerts").html(data.responseText);

                if (data.updated) {
                    var place  = ".table3 tbody tr:nth-child("+data.index+") " ;
                    var des    = place+" > *";
                    $( place ).load("http://localhost:8000/manage_contents/ "+des, function(){
                    });
                }

            },
            error: function(data,xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                $.each(data.responseJSON, function(){
                    var i = 1;
                    $.each(this, function(index,error) {
                        $("#inputField"+i).addClass(" has-error");
                        $("#help-block"+i).removeClass(" hideme");
                        $("#help-block"+i).html("<strong>"+error+"</strong>");
                        i++;
                    });
                });

            },
        })
    });
});




});
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect its happening due to your HTML `form` is getting loaded via `ajax` and before that only your `$(document).ready(` code is getting executed. Hence at that time there will be no element with id `edit-content-form` present in DOM. So to deal with this situation try using event delegation technique like below:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('submit','#edit-content-form',function(e){

     // your existing code goes here

    });
});
```

We are attaching the event listener to the `document` object which will be there for sure and then delegating to `#edit-content-form` whenever event occurs.

Comment: i tried ur suggestion but it's the same no change happened.